# Agreement feature extraction from a text

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I'm going through a task where i have to extract the agreement feature of the nouns in the text...
The agreement feature such as:

```
number = singular, plural
person = first, second, third
gender = male, female, neuter
animacy = animate, inanimate
```

is there anyway to extract these features from the text ....

Comment: You would really have to check every line,find the noun tags,and then have a list of agreement features(as you call it) to be cross checked again the one's found in the line.

Comment: you mean i should check each line of the parser or the text it self .. coz the singular and plural nouns i can extract them by POS tagger. what about the other features, is it possible to extract them using NLP open source !

Comment: The stanford-nlp POS tagger uses the `Penn Treebank POS tagset`. So unfortunately, you can only access singular and plural nouns from those tags. Either you need to search for a tagset that has such supported features, or manually make a parser to search for such attributes.

Comment: And I think even open-nlp uses the same tagset.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is English, as your comments suggest, then the nouns will never have person information, so we can discount that.

Number is easy, as has been mentioned by others: many part-of-speech taggers differentiate between singular and plural nouns.

Gender and animacy are more interesting. In English, these are semantic rather than syntactic properties of nouns. For example, take the sentence *The princess is in the tower*. We know that *princess* is feminine and animate not because of inflectional information but because we know the word's meaning. It's feasible to build up an ontology by getting a big old corpus of data and analysing the pronouns and anaphors in it. Your algorithm would look for examples like these:

*The princess looks at herself in the mirror.*

*The princess is in the tower. She is sad.*

It would work out (somehow) that *princess* is the antecedent of *herself* and *her*, and infer the properties of the noun from the known properties of the pronouns. Of course, now the problem becomes reference resolution, which isn't trivial. Here are some references from a recent Edinburgh University lecture course on the subject:

- Denis, Pascal and Baldridge, Jason, 2008. 'Specialized Models and Reranking for Coreference Resolution.' In *Proceedings of the Conference on Empirical Methods in Natural Language Processing*. ACL, 650-69.
- Haghighi, Aria and Klein, Dan, 2010. 'Coreference Resolution in a Modular, Entity-Centred Model.' In *Human Language Technologies: The 2010 Annual Conference of the North American Chapter of the Association for Computational Linguistics*. Los Angeles CA, 385-93.
- Lappin, Shalom and Leass, Herbert, 1994. 'An Algorithm for Pronominal Anaphora Resolution.' *Computational Linguistics* 20:535-61.
- Ng, Vincent, 2010. 'Supervised Noun Phrase Coreference Research: The first 15 years.' In *ACL '10: Proceedings of the 48th Meeting of the Association for Computational Linguistics.* 1396-411.

Comment: thanks Tommy Herbert, it's really helpful what you have been explained especially the Anaphora Resolution... how about the names which doesn't have any pronouns that connected to it. how we can figure out it's gender and animacy. what about the names that starts with Mr, Miss, Queen, Lady, Lord  ..... is there any approach for these words or open source that have been doing on this thing !

Comment: Oh, well I think those would be much easier. It's a fairly limited list of titles. Compile it by hand and have your tagger look out for them. I don't know whether there's an existing open source implementation.